# Python: Blender does not print error

Tags: python, scripting

I write Add-on using two callback functions, modal timer operator and binary module. When I develop this Add-on, then I write bug sometimes, but Python sometimes silently "die" and no error is printed to terminal. Do you have any advice?

Edit: problem was in Python binary module. Following code was wrong:

```
session_SessionObject *session = session_list[session_id];
if(session != NULL) {
    PyObject_CallMethod((PyObject*)session, "cb_receive_layer_destroy", "(IH)",
            node_id, layer_id);
}
return;
```

because it didn't check for return value of `PyObject_CallMethod` and it didn't try to "catch" errors from Python callback method. Following code is right:

```
session_SessionObject *session = session_list[session_id];
if(session != NULL) {
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    result = PyObject_CallMethod((PyObject*)session, "cb_receive_layer_destroy", "(IH)",
            node_id, layer_id);
    if(result == NULL || PyErr_Occurred() != NULL) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
}
return;
```

Comment: Hey Jiri, Python should always print errors, though sometimes they don't show in as a message in the UI depending on the context, could you give an example script which shows this behavior?

Comment: Hi Campbell, I can't give you simple example of the script. The WIP code can be found at github: https://github.com/verse/verse-blender. It is very complex add-on and it uses binary module using pthreads.

Comment: Often time codes will create new variables when ones mentioned are not defined, what type of bug did you write?

Comment: May be, there is problem with binary module: https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html#intermezzo-errors-and-exceptions

Comment: I found problem and solution, but I'm not sure if it is right place for such questions (may be, stackoverflow.com would be better).